# ExtJS 4.2 layout crush on latest chrome but not on old one in full screen

Tags: geoext, ext-js, chrome, ext-js-4

I've noticed that only in chrome my GeoExt app crush when I open many layers.
If I resize the window , the layout seems to look good , once I resize to bigger screen , it mess again.

The app code didn't change for long time , it doesn't happen on old laptop with chrome version 27 it only happens on 2 stronger desktops with latest chrome version.

**UPDATE**

I've found out that commenting the following CSS in openlayers resolve the problem , Any idea why ?

```
  /**
 * Animations
 */

      .olLayerGrid .olTileImage {
        /*-webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;*/
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
        /*transition: opacity 0.2s linear;*/
    }

    /* Turn on GPU support where available */
    .olTileImage {
        /*-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);*/
        -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -o-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
        /*transform: translateZ(0);*/
        /*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;*/
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-perspective: 1000;
        -moz-perspective: 1000;
        -ms-perspective: 1000;
        perspective: 1000;
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have had a similar problem recently. I got around it by reinstalling Chrome but I have no idea whether this will fix your problem.

Comment: I have tried re installing it , and problem still exist.
You can try it on your PC also : http://tinyurl.com/p824qnk click the check-boxes on the right till all layers open , suddenly it will happen

Comment: Can confirm it happens here too. Very strange. Sorry I cant be of more assistance.

Comment: @JamesS - Can you confirm that in other browsers it doesn't happen ? I have no idea why only chrome.

Comment: Yep works fine on IE9 and Firefox 26.0.

Comment: Same here , So ... what should I do !?

Comment: I find it only happens when I have a window with a width of  more than roughly 1540 pixels (I measured the size using this tool - http://www.arulerforwindows.com/). Under this size and it displays correctly. Do you get the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As updated in the original post , this is how I solved it eventually.

In OpenLayers css commented out :

```
/**
 * Animations
 */

      .olLayerGrid .olTileImage {
        /*-webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;*/
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
        /*transition: opacity 0.2s linear;*/
    }

    /* Turn on GPU support where available */
    .olTileImage {
        /*-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);*/
        -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -o-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
        /*transform: translateZ(0);*/
        /*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;*/
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-perspective: 1000;
        -moz-perspective: 1000;
        -ms-perspective: 1000;
        perspective: 1000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are old and constant stability problems when running ExtJS applications based, on Chrome:

- [the latest Chrome crashes on animation in ExtJs 4 charts and draws them incorrectly](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?192862)
- [ExtJS 4.2.1 calendar demo in sencha.com crashes in chrome](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?274890)

These problems have been reported to Sencha and Google:

- [SVG Rendering issue with Highcharts charting library](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112713&can=1&q=tspan&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary)

In time, there were new Chrome and ExtJS versions, which brought some improvements:

- [Ext JS 4.2.1 GA is Now Available!](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?264700)

Unfortunately, again, some users have reported errors:

- [App is undefined in Chrome version 28](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?270070)

In this situation, I think you need to test the latest Chrome with different ExtJS versions (like 4.2.1, 4.2.2 or newer revisions) and hope your application isn't affected by the latest incompatibility.

Comment: I'm using latest GPL licensed Ext 4.2.1
Can't try newer ExtJS because its not GPL yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and after hours of messing around with it I found that adding padding:'10 0 10 0' to your center region of your viewport will fix the issue.

Comment: Do you mean adding padding to the mapPanel ? tried mapPanel = Ext.create('GIS.view.Map', {padding:"10px 0px 10px 0px",map: map, tbar: toolbar, bbar: bToolBar, title: appTitle }); and it didn't solve the problem

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?279834-ExtJs-components-disappear-on-Chrome-resize-to-full-screen&p=1023185  The last post there better describes what i had to do.

Comment: darn , this didn't solve my problem... but maybe i didn't add it correctly :-/